# Communicate Android Device to Localhost (My Windows 8 PC) over / via USB Cable

Tags: java, android, windows, usb, localhost

I have Android Device Samsung GT OS 2.2.1

and i have succeeded Send HTTP Request to my Localhost (My Windows 8 PC) over WIFI

but, considering of speed, i also want to learn "How to send HTTP Request to localhost my windows 8 PC over USB"

this is my code to send over WIFI

```
URL url = null;
        try {
            /*Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection*/
        url = new URL("http://192.168.xxx.xxx/MySkripsi/testWriteFile.php");
        String body = "";
        body += "text=" + messageTujuan;

        byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStream  out = conn.getOutputStream(); 
        out.write(bytes);
        out.close();
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (status != 200) {
            Toast.makeText(con, "status = " + status , 0).show();
        }
        else
        {
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append((line + "\n"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close(); 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(con, "Return Nya = " +sb.toString(), 0).show();
            Log.v("TEST" , "Return Nya = " + sb.toString());
            tv.setText(sb.toString());
            is.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() + "#" + e.getMessage(), 0).show();
    }
```

this code, give me result

but whenever i turn off the WIFI
it shows

"java.net.SocketException: Network Unreachable"

so i research it through some website, and i found this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191930/Android-Usb-Port-Forwarding

here is the print screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY8SI.jpg

and USB Tunnel in my android device also say that "Service is running, Connected !"

but , with the same code as above, 
except :

```
url = new URL("h**p://127.0.0.1:80/MySkripsi/testWriteFile.php");
```

the result is 
"java.netConnectException :/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused"

i think there is something wrong with my firewall , but i dont know how to fix it

so my question is

is there any other method that can be used to communicate between android to server?

i really need **my android device to Send Data** to my localhost (Windows 8 pc) as my server 
and **receive server's response over USB**

thanks..

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is always "this device", whichever device it's on. If you're trying to open it from your Android device, it's going to try to contact the Android device itself, not your Windows machine. You have to use your server's IP address.

Comment: in my ipconfig
it says that 
192.168.11.1 as Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection
and
192.168.45.179 as Ethernet adapter Ethernet.

I've tried 
url=new URL("h**p://192.168.45.179:80/MySkripsi/testWriteFile.php");
and 
url=new URL("h**p://192.168.11.1:80/MySkripsi/testWriteFile.php");
and 
url=new URL("h**p://192.168.45.179/MySkripsi/testWriteFile.php");
and 
url=new URL("h**p://192.168.45.179/MySkripsi/testWriteFile.php");

, but all of it says ' Network unreachable '

Comment: You need to learn about basic TCP/IP networking; `Network unreachable` means that your IP addresses aren't on the same subnet and you don't have a router available. If `ping` doesn't work, then your HTTP connections won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I developed one application which connect my jsp file.here the sample code.

```
              try
                 {

                    URL url = new URL("http:/xx.xxx.xxx.x:80/sample.jsp");
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                     String x = "";
                     String total = "";
                     int i=0;
                     ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList();
                     while((x = r.readLine()) != null)
                     {
                                 content.add(x);

                     }
                     in.close();
                     r.close();
                 }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     Toast.makeText(Customer.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
```

So,you can make change(in url) this code as your wish.If you want to run in usb means, you have to download samsung usb driver to your pc and then you run the application.Before that you enable developer option in your device.

Comment: i think your code is the same as mine Ram, it seems that my problem here is my device cannot send http over usb , but thanks man

Comment: @Yogie Soesanto Over USB means,USB modem?.

Comment: USB Cable , Which connect PC with Android Device

Comment: @Yogie Soesanto How you run ur application?either manually put ur apk in device or directly run in device using IDE?..

Comment: i use eclipse , so i guess it is an IDE, then right click then run app

Comment: @Yogie Soesanto check your url is correct using the browser.and also ping the ip from your system.you can view your IP using the command "ipconfig" in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Ram and @chyrlis

i want to share it, maybe it will help the others

so i just googled everywhere , and they all tell me about usb tether

here is what i did to solve my own problem

1. in my pc , i type cmd > ipconfig

and there isn't any ethernet for my android device

1. i TURN ON the "USB TETHERING" (I'm Using Android Froyo GT-S5830) 
   (Note that , when i googled, they all told me that not every device has "USB TETHERING")
2. then i type cmd > ipconfig again

and THERE IS one ethernet for my android devie , with ip = 192.168.42.201 
(Note that this IP is dynamic [DHCP], so maybe you can change it to static first)
here is the tutorial 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIYyRYdV7B8

so i changed my IP to 192.168.42.202

1. using my own code

i changed the url to

```
"url = new URL("http://192.168.42.202/MySkripsi/testWriteFile.php");"
```

NOTE THAT 192.168.42.201 is the IP i got from ipconfig
and i changed my IP to 192.168.42.202 so it will be static IP

1. and BAM
   there it is , i can use my http request from my device and get the response from my server

hope it helps